# Add leading zeroes to string, without (s)printf

Tags: c++

I want to add a variable of leading zero's to a string.
I couldn't find anything on Google, without someone mentioning `(s)printf`,
but I want to do this without `(s)printf`.

Does anybody of the readers know a way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
// assuming that `original_string` is of type `std:string`:

std::string dest = std::string( number_of_zeros, '0').append( original_string);
```

Comment: Doesn't this will just add zeros without taken into account the "original_string" length? 
`number_of_zeros = 4
original_string = "99"
dest will become: 000099 (and not 0099)`. Please correct me if I'm wrong or I perhaps don't understand what 'leading zeros' really mean...

Comment: @lepe It answers the question as written. Whether the OP wrote what they really meant is a different matter.

Answer (score 129):

I can give this one-line solution if you want a field of `n_zero` zeros:

```
auto new_str = std::string(n_zero - std::min(n_zero, old_str.length()), '0') + old_str;
```

For example, for `std::string old_str = "45"; size_t n_zero = 4;` you get `new_str == "0045"`.

Comment: I like this.  It means I don't have to construct a stringstream, which has quite some baggage with respect to internals.

Comment: Very nice solution!  What happens when (n_zero - old_string.length()) is negative?  EDIT: Just tested it, it appears to still work passing a negative value.

Comment: @Castaa The argument for the number of characters is an `std::string::size_type`, which like most size types in the stdlib is unsigned. So, if the user passes a negative number, that gets wrapped around and will result in a large positive number. So, it should "work" but probably not do the expected/useful thing (hence why unsigned size types are bad, m'kay).

Comment: added a fix concerning the integer overflow

Comment: @RuslanGuseinov `string.length()` returns `size_t` which `std::min` complains about.

Comment: @lys added a clarification for expected types, in particular n_zero should be of type size_t, then it is also compatible with std::string constructor that we use.

Answer (score 66):

You could use [`std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert), [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) with [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill), or [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/format/doc/format.html) :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  std::string s("12");
  s.insert(0, 3, '0');
  std::cout << s << "\n";

  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << 12 << "\n";
  std::string s2(ss.str());
  std::cout << s2;

  boost::format fmt("%05d\n");
  fmt % 12;
  std::string s3 = fmt.str();
  std::cout << s3;
}
```

Comment: An application: To pad out an integer to 20 characters: `auto padded = std::to_string(num); padded.insert(0, 20U - std::min(std::string::size_type(20), padded.length()), '0');` The `min` keeps you from wrapping around if the string you are trying to pad is too long. (20 characters won't have this problem for any integer under 64 bits). The cast to `size_type` is needed because min complains about mismatches on some platforms.

Comment: I wish you could explain that first example using `std::string`

Answer (score 33):

You could do something like:

```
std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << 1;
```

This should print `00001`.

Note, however, that the fill-character is "sticky", so when you're done using zero-filling, you'll have to use `std::cout << std::setfill(' ');` to get the usual behavior again.

Comment: Nah, thanks for your input but its the same way using sprintf (:

Comment: does not seem to be sticky. `std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << 1 << 1 << std::endl;` produces: `000011`

Comment: @AleksanderFular `std::setw` is not sticky. `std::setfill` is sticky, but it's not much use without an oversized width to give it something to do. So your first `1` gets the `setw(5)` and hence has leading zeroes prepended, but then the `setw` is dropped back to default, so your second `1` just gets printed as `1`. So, `00001` + `1` = `000011`. The point is that if you later set `setw`, you'd find that the previous `setfill` character was still in effect, because `setfill` isn't sticky => doesn't get reset to its default of a space.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This works well for me. You don't need to switch setfill back to ' ', as this a temporary stream.

```
std::string to_zero_lead(const int value, const unsigned precision)
{
     std::ostringstream oss;
     oss << std::setw(precision) << std::setfill('0') << value;
     return oss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to modify the original string instead of creating a copy, you can use `std::string::insert()`.

```
std::string s = "123";
unsigned int number_of_zeros = 5 - s.length(); // add 2 zeros

s.insert(0, number_of_zeros, '0');
```

Result:

```
00123
```

Answer (score 1):

```
memcpy(target,'0',sizeof(target));
target[sizeof(target)-1] = 0;
```

Then stick whatever string you want zero prefixed at the end of the buffer.

If it is an integer number, remember `log_base10(number)+1` (aka `ln(number)/ln(10)+1`) gives you the length of the number.

Comment: Nah, thanks for the try but I want to be able to add a variable amount of zero's.

Comment: @Guus: That *is* a variable number of zeros.  However, you can replace the (sizeof(target)) with some other number if it would make you happy.

Comment: @Guus: Specifically, from your comment below, you wanted %05d, right?  If the buffer is six characters long, that is exactly what my code would do for you (at least the zero fill part, putting the number at the end was left for you).