# how to format out in c++?

Tags: c++

I know how to use printf() to format output of float, for example:

```
float i = 1;
printf("%.2f", i);
```

but how to format the output using `cout` to output 2 digits after "."?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143824/c-add-leading-zeros-to-string-without-sprintf/6143927#6143927

Comment: @Ozair: What do leading zeroes have to do with it?

Comment: @Tomalak: It is just pointed out to take a hint. Otherwise I would have posted it as an answer.

Comment: @Ozair: A hint of something completely unrelated? Ok....

Comment: This is something that google can answer in seconds, google "cout format options" and go "I feel lucky" HINT `setprecision(2)`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119098/which-i-o-library-do-you-use-in-your-c-code/119194#119194

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following will do:

```
std::cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(2)<<i;
```

You will also need to include iomanip

Comment: Would be more elegant with some spaces to make it legible :P

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << setprecision(2) << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << 3.141592 << endl;
}
```

use setprecision().

Answer (score 1):

A red herring is to use `std::setprecision` on its own:

```
float f = 3.1415;
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << f;
```

However, "precision" is *not* the same as "number of decimal places", as shown in [this example](http://codepad.org/E89CEDBX).

Fortunately, and somewhat confusingly, switching the stream to "fixed-point" display changes the meaning of `std::setprecision` to something more akin to "setDecimalPlaces".

So, [you can write this](http://codepad.org/xlHRnFoK):

```
float f = 3.1415;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << f;
```

Comment: To be more precise the without fixed it rounds off the number to the number of digits entered as argument.....:)

Comment: @Abhimanyu: Yes. Precision in non-fixed mode specifies the number of _significant figures_.

Answer (score 1):

Boost format helps:

```
std::cout << boost::format("%.2f") % i;
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps.........

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  double f =3.14159;
  cout << setprecision (5) << f << endl;
  cout << setprecision (9) << f << endl;
  cout << fixed;
  cout << setprecision (5) << f << endl;
  cout << setprecision (9) << f << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

output..

```
> 3.1416
> 3.14159
> 3.14159
> 3.141590000
```

Comment: cplusplus.com is a ghastly "resource".

Comment: @Abhimanyu: (a) You didn't format your post correctly. I edited it for you. (b) No, it's not sufficient. My example of your code clearly demonstrates that.

Comment: it is doing the same thing it is supposed to do......displaying the number of digits you want to see....let me edit my post...

Comment: @Abhimanyu: No, it's not. In the codepad example I ask for 2dp and get 1. This is clearly displayed on the screen. You are confusing "precision" with "decimal places". `std::fixed` changes the meaning of `std::setprecision` (somewhat confusingly) to "setdecimalplaces", but your answer does not employ this.

Comment: @tomalak....that is why i added the link for reference.....what i mentioned was for calculating the roundoff to the digits u want to see.....and if you want to do something else thats why the link was for...

Comment: @Abhimanyu: So you wrote an answer that _does not answer the question_, including code that does not do what the OP wants it to do, reasoning that the link you provided to a sub-par internet resource happens to contain the real answer somewhere therein? You also wrote "number of digits after decimal u want" in a previous edit, showing that in fact you were _not_ aware of this at all.

Comment: @tomalak.....now u r happy.........whats the point posting it from another site...?the ques was simple and needed a simple answer and didnt find the need write the whole thing coz if the person is program a simple hint could be sufficient enough to help him....we don't really need to spoonfeed the....

Comment: @Abhimanyu: Regardless, you posted code that basically said "insert number of decimal places required here", that then did not display the number of decimal places entered.

Comment: and i have finally edited also.........there was a slight msitake which i edited the first tym itself....but still u were able to deduce that i know nothing about it....how come???

Comment: @Abhimanyu: You also wrote "number of digits after decimal u want" in a previous edit, showing that in fact you were not aware of this at all. I'm not going to comment on this thread again.

Comment: Chill down guyz. We are here to make a better world not to fight over it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x = 800000.0/81.0;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2) << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << ffmt(0, 2) << i;
```

Where `ffmt` is defined as:

```
class ffmt
{
    int width;
    int precision;
public:
    ffmt( int width, int precision )
        : width( width )
        , precision( precision )
    {
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(
        std::ostream& dest,
        ffmt const& manip )
    {
        dest.setf( std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield );
        dest.width( width );
        dest.precision( precision );
    }
};
```

You can also extend this to restore format state at the end of the full
expression; it's not too important for floating point, because most of
the time, you'll use the manipulator in front of each output, but a
manipulator which leaves the stream outputting hex is likely to lead to
surprising output later.

As a general rule, except for quicky demo or test programs, you almost
never use the standard manipulators, other that `std::setw`.  For that
matter, in a lot of applications, you'll even avoid things like `ffmt`,
in favor of specific manipulators for each semantic value you have.