# how to zero pre-fill for std::to_string function?

Tags: c++, string, printing

In C++ using std::to_string(), how should I pre-fill a string converted from integer? I tried using #include  and std::setfill('0') but it didn't work. here's the simple test code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include <iomanip> // setw, setfill below doesn't work

int main()
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<20;i++){
    std::cout << "without zero fill : " << std::to_string(i) << ", with zero fill : " << std::to_string(i) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << "without zero fill : " << std::to_string(i) << ", with zero fill : " << std::to_string(i) << std::endl;  // doesn't work
}
}
```

What I want to do is, to have some numbers converted into string, but some of them with zero padding, the others not.(I'm using it to make filename actually.) How should I do it?
(I don't know why this should be not so simple as in C using %0d or %04d format specifier.)

ADD : From [Add leading zero's to string, without (s)printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143824/add-leading-zeros-to-string-without-sprintf), I found

```
int number = 42;
int leading = 3; //6 at max
std::to_string(number*0.000001).substr(8-leading); //="042"
```

This works for me, but I'd prefer more natural solution, than this trick like method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `std::to_string()`, you could use a `std::ostringstream`. The IO manipulators will work with a `std::ostringstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
   for ( int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i )
   {
      std::ostringstream str;
      str << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << i;
      std::cout << str.str() << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/ay0Xzp.

Comment: I see, thanks, but what if I want the final value as 'string' not 'ostringstream'? I want to use it as part of filename forming..

Comment: I see. that works! maybe I should understand this ostringstream. Why is the prints merged if I declarer it outside the for loop?

Comment: @ChanKim, because in that case you are adding to the contents of the `ostringstream` object. By having it defined inside the loop, a new one is constructed in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 8):

`ostringstream` seems to be an overkill. You can simply insert the number of zeros you need:

```
template<typename T/*, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>*/>
std::string to_string_with_zero_padding(const T& value, std::size_t total_length)
{
    auto str = std::to_string(value);
    if (str.length() < total_length)
        str.insert(str.front() == '-' ? 1 : 0, total_length - str.length(), '0');
    return str;
}
```

This function also works correctly if the `value` is negative and/or if `T` is `char` or related type.

Comment: Great idea. But some recommendations: 1) un-templatize it (avoids unnecessary recompilation in unchanged files), 2) add default to not fill, if not specified, and 3) parameterize the fill char used.    `std::string toString (int val, std::size_t padLen = 0, char padChar = '0')`

Comment: @automorphic I don't think it should be made a non-template function. We have many different integral types besides `int` (`std::to_string` has 9 overloads for different types).

Comment: Understood. For most projects, `int` would suffice. Untemplatizing it isn't really an improvement - just a simplification. But the other two improvements are the important ones, in that they extend the usefullness of your code without changing your logic. Thanks!