# How can I convert military time to regular time. the regular time must be a string

Tags: c++, c++17

I hope someone can help me. I keep getting one 0 on the minutes side. for example, for input 0000 I get 12:0 AM or for input 608 I get 6:8 AM. How can I get double 0 on the minutes side?

on main.cc I have:

```
#include "time_converter.h"
#include <iostream>



int main() {
  int military_time;
  std::cout << "Please enter the time in military time: ";
  std::cin >> military_time;
  
  // TODO: Call your function to convert from military time to regular time
  // and assign its result to regular_time.

std::string regular_time;
regular_time = MilitaryToRegularTime(military_time);


  std::cout << "The equivalent regular time is: " << regular_time << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

time_converter.h:

```
#include <iostream>

// Converts the time in military format to regular format.
std::string MilitaryToRegularTime(int military_time);
```

time_converter.cc:

```
#include <iostream>


std::string amorpm;
std::string MilitaryToRegularTime(int military_time) {
  // TODO: convert military_time to regular time in string format.
  // Hint: std::to_string() converts a given integer to a string. 
  
  
   int regular_hr = military_time / 100;
    if (regular_hr >= 13){
       regular_hr = (military_time / 100) - 12;
        }
    
    if (regular_hr == 0){
    regular_hr = 12;
    }
   
   int regular_min = military_time % 100;
    
    if (military_time >= 1200 && military_time <= 2359){
  amorpm = " PM\n";
 
    }
    if (military_time >= 0000 && military_time <= 1159 ){
  amorpm = " AM\n";
    }


   std::string regular_hr_str = std::to_string(regular_hr);
   std::string regular_min_str = std::to_string(regular_min);
 

  return regular_hr_str + ":" + regular_min_str + amorpm;
}
```

Comment: [how to zero pre-fill for std::to_string function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475501/how-to-zero-pre-fill-for-stdto-string-function) may help. You could just check the length of the string, and if it's less than 2 `str.insert(0, 1, '0');` or any other method to prepend the 0.

Comment: Please note that your question would be of higher quality if you provided a [mre] of the problem. Since your actual problem has nothing to do with converting time, only with printing time, it is not necessary to post all that code about converting time.

Answer (score 0):

The function `std::to_string` does not have sufficient formatting options to do what you require.

However, if you instead use an object of type [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) as the target, you can use the [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) I/O manipulators to accomplish what you want. You can use `std::setw` to set the minimum width to `2` and `std::setfill` to set the fill character to `'0'`.

After you are finished, you can convert the `std::ostringstream` object to a `std::string` using [`std::ostringstream::str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int hours = 6;
    int minutes = 8;

    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::string str;

    //write desired time to ostringstream object
    oss <<
        "The time is " <<
        std::setw( 2 ) << std::setfill( '0' ) <<
        hours <<
        ":" <<
        std::setw( 2 ) << std::setfill( '0' ) <<
        minutes <<
        ".\n";

    //convert ostringstream to a string
    str = oss.str();

    //print the string
    std::cout << "String content: " << str << '\n';
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
String content: The time is 06:08.
```